# nginx-ingress https redirect for IE11/Win8.1 not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, internet-explorer-11, windows-8.1, nginx-ingress

**Setup Overview**

I have setup on GCP a Kubernetes cluster last week (1.15.12-gke.2) using the latest nginx-ingress helm chart (App version: 0.34.1, Chart Version: ingress-nginx-2.12.1)

For the website I made a basic echoheader deployment exposing the app via an ingress object configured with the `force-ssl-redirect=true` annotation.

**Symptom**

When visiting the site with IE11 on Windows 8.1 (It has to be explicitly this version) then I get a "This page can’t be displayed" message.

Even when I implement the fix from this [Github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1825#issuecomment-361550417) into the environment I will still get the same issue. The picture is the same error for http or https.

[image: IE error]

Does anybody have an idea how I can debug or solve this? I am right now stuck without any idea how to further Analyse the problem.

Comment: can you show deployment, service and ingress yamls? it doesnt work in any browser?

Comment: Does the website work well in other browsers or can work well in IE 11 in other machines? You can use F12 dev tools to debug the page. You can try to check if there's any error in console and use Network tab to check the network traffic. Besides, you can also refer to the [troubleshooting part](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting) of the NGINX Ingress doc.

Answer (score 3):

Just kill the default **RC4+RSA** ssl cipher and it's saul goodman

Use this

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-ciphers: "ALL:!aNULL:!EXPORT56:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP"
```

Works fine for me

It's not accepted by Internet Explorer anymore https://support.microsoft.com/help/3151631/rc4-cipher-is-no-longer-supported-in-internet-explorer-11-or-microsoft

Source right here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-ciphers

Enjoy